# After transfered the ownership to one contract, how to transfer it to others?

Tags: solidity

Here 2 contracts: contract A and contract B

If I (deployer/owner) transferred the ownership of contract A to contract B, is there any solutions that can transfer the ownership of contract A from contract B to others?

What I can come up with is I have to write some functions in contract B to transfer the ownership of contract A to others. Any other better ideas?

THank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

Contracts don't have any concept of an "owner" by default. Contracts only have the functionality you write into them.

A quite common scenario is that functionality is added, which creates the concept of "owner" and assigns it to the contract deployer. This is for example what the OpenZeppelin `Ownable` contract is for: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol . It also has functionality to transfer ownership.

Comment: Yep. I exactly used the OpenZeppelin `Ownable` contract to do this. My question is after I transferred the ownership of contract A to contract B, how to transfer the ownership of contract A from contract B to others? Do I need write some function in contract B to implement this?

Comment: The Ownable contract has functionality to transfer ownership onwards. So the current owner has to call this function: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L63